# Firefox 122.0. Extensions. "chrome.scripting.executeScript" removes ":" (colon) from url when using in double with protocol url

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The following code for Firefox extensions (addons) was working fine on Firefox until 122.0 version:

**background.js**:

```
function openUrl(url) {
    window.open(url, '_self');
}

function play(url) {
    chrome.tabs.query( {currentWindow: true, active : true}, function(tabs) {
        let urlFinaly = "steam://" + url;
        if (devMode) console.log(urlFinaly);
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: tabs[0].id}, func: openUrl, args: [urlFinaly]});
    });
}
```

in Firefox Console it prints:

`steam://https://www.example.com`

but in Windows program I get `https//` instead of `https://`:

`https//www.example.com`

For Firefox 121.* and earlier it works fine, and also it works fine for newest Google Chrome browser - the link can be successfully passed correctly to the program like

How can I fix it for new version of Firefox?

Comment: Report the problem to Firefox developers as it's a bug.

Comment: @wOxxOm they gave me a solution - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1876731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received an answer from Bugzilla:

Change the code to be:

```js
let urlFinal = "steam:" + url;
```

That should create a URL that looks like `steam:https://www.example.com` and should work to pass the URL to an external program.

Now it works

**UPDATED**: the same behavior will on all other browsers: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1416006